Minimize line breaks in a table
I have some table with content powered by an API, I'd like to let the content size naturally but am running into some odd line breaks.


img {
  height: 24px;
}
table {
  width: 600px;
}
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th>Cool</th>
         <th>Upgrade</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/productlogos/youtube_go_ios/v10/192px.svg"></td>
         <td>A very long description and it's going to run over two lines because it's super duper amazingly crazy long</td>
         <td><img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/googlesymbols/done/default/24px.svg"></td>
         <td><img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/googlesymbols/done/default/24px.svg"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/productlogos/youtube_go_ios/v10/192px.svg"></td>
         <td>A kinda long description</td>
         <td>10 GB</td>
         <td>10 TB</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>



In the above example the super long description is so long that it will always spill into two lines, but it shrinks the "10 GB" cell so that it is two lines which is undesirable.
Without using any specific sizing rule on any particular column, is there a way to make this size in a way that minimizes the line breaks when they aren't necessary?

You can suppress line breaks in selected columns using white-space: nowrap.


img {
  height: 24px;
}
table {
  width: 600px;
}
td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(4) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th>Cool</th>
         <th>Upgrade</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/productlogos/youtube_go_ios/v10/192px.svg"></td>
         <td>A very long description and it's going to run over two lines because it's super duper amazingly crazy long</td>
         <td><img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/googlesymbols/done/default/24px.svg"></td>
         <td><img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/googlesymbols/done/default/24px.svg"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/productlogos/youtube_go_ios/v10/192px.svg"></td>
         <td>A kinda long description</td>
         <td>10 GB</td>
         <td>10 TB</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>



